# get nearest coordinate from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, coordinates, distance

I have a point coordinate based on two double values `x0,y0` both in this format: xx.x (point as decimal separator)

In a database I have a list of lines that are defined by the coordinates `x1,y1` as startpoint and `x2,y2` as endpoint. Among other columns, (such as line thickness and so on) in the database there are these columns:

`id | x1 | y1 | x2 | y2`

What I would need is a query that returns whatever line has either the starpoint(x1,y1) or the endpoint(x2,y2) nearest to my basepoint (x0,y0). So the line that starts or ends nearest to my current position.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: yes it is a cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: You need to 1. compute the distance between two points, 2. get the smaller of the two distances, and 3. get the row with the smalles such distance. Which of these three steps do you have a problem with?

Comment: all three of them since it should be done in a single query.. would be easy to do outside but i have no clue on how to do it in a query since sqlite is quite limited..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no square root function, but for comparing distances, we can just as well use the square of the distance:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY min((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0),
             (x2-x0)*(x2-x0) + (y2-y0)*(y2-y0))
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thank you! order by min (distance1, distance2), what happens if distance 2 is the smallest?

Comment: Have a look at the [min() documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#minoreunc).